# How to stop Nav Button scrolling with page when active

Tags: html, css

I have burger/X icons for mobile nav menu.  When closed the burger stays in position as it should. When menu is open the X icon scrolls with the menu. Any ideas to keep it in place?

```css
#ham {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  z-index: 125;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#ham.active {
  top: -20px;
  left: -10px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

#ham .fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
  font-style: normal;
}

.active .fa-bars {
  display: none;
}

#ham .fa-window-close {
  display: none;
}

.active .fa-window-close {
  display: inline-block !important;
  color: #303030;
  font-style: normal;
  transition: transform 0.6s easeInSine;
}
```

```html
<span class="" id="ham" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Please include all applicable code, including JS.

Comment: Did you try to give it a fixed position in mobile nav menu

Comment: No JS is used here, other than the onClick  ...I have tried fixed, absolute, and relative and still scrolls with the menu